# Extracting Text Data with Location

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, extract

I've been successful extracting character data with position data from pdfs but when I am trying to extract words with position data the text doesn't always come out as single words. Things like Saskatchewan could be split into S A SKA TCH EWAN. Is there anyway to fix this? I came across similar issues but the answers were for older versions of itextsharp.

```
  public class TextLocationStrategy : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
  {

    public static List<PdfText> CharacterResult = new List<PdfText>();
    public static List<PdfText> WordResult = new List<PdfText>();

    protected override bool IsChunkAtWordBoundary(TextChunk chunk, TextChunk previousChunk)
    {
      float dist = chunk.GetLocation().DistanceFromEndOf(previousChunk);
      if (dist < -chunk.GetLocation().GetCharSpaceWidth() || dist > chunk.GetLocation().GetCharSpaceWidth() / 4.0f)
      {
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    }

    public override void EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
    {
      try
      {
        if (!type.Equals(EventType.RENDER_TEXT))
        {
          return;
        }

        TextRenderInfo renderInfo = (TextRenderInfo)data;
        string curFont = renderInfo.GetFont().GetFontProgram().ToString();
        float curFontSize = renderInfo.GetFontSize();
        IList<TextRenderInfo> text = renderInfo.GetCharacterRenderInfos();

        string curText = renderInfo.GetText();
        if (curText != " " && !curText.Contains(' '))
        {
          Vector wordStart = renderInfo.GetBaseline().GetStartPoint();
          Vector wordEnd = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();
          Rectangle wordRect = new Rectangle(wordStart.Get(0), wordStart.Get(1), wordEnd.Get(0) - wordStart.Get(0), wordEnd.Get(1) - wordStart.Get(1));

          PdfText chunk = new PdfText
          {
            Text = curText,
            Rectangle = wordRect,
            FontFamily = curFont,
            FontSize = Convert.ToInt32(curFontSize),
            SpaceWidth = renderInfo.GetSingleSpaceWidth(),
            HorizontalScaling = renderInfo.GetHorizontalScaling(),
            Leading = renderInfo.GetLeading(),
            CharacterSpacing = renderInfo.GetCharSpacing(),
            StartPoint = new Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry.Point3d(wordStart.Get(0), wordStart.Get(1), 0.0),
            EndPoint = new Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry.Point3d(wordEnd.Get(0), wordEnd.Get(1), 0.0)
          };
          WordResult.Add(chunk);
        }

        foreach (TextRenderInfo t in text)
        {
          string letter = t.GetText();
          Vector letterStart = t.GetBaseline().GetStartPoint();
          Vector letterEnd = t.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();
          Rectangle letterRect = new Rectangle(letterStart.Get(0), letterStart.Get(1), letterEnd.Get(0) - letterStart.Get(0), letterEnd.Get(1) - letterStart.Get(1));

          if (letter != " " && !letter.Contains(' '))
          {
            PdfText chunk = new PdfText
            {
              Text = letter,
              Rectangle = letterRect,
              FontFamily = curFont,
              FontSize = Convert.ToInt32(curFontSize),
              SpaceWidth = t.GetSingleSpaceWidth(),
              HorizontalScaling = t.GetHorizontalScaling(),
              Leading = t.GetLeading(),
              CharacterSpacing = t.GetCharSpacing(),
              StartPoint = new Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry.Point3d(letterStart.Get(0), letterStart.Get(1), 0.0),
              EndPoint = new Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry.Point3d(letterEnd.Get(0), letterEnd.Get(1), 0.0)
            };
            CharacterResult.Add(chunk);
          }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        ErrorManager.ReportError(ex);
      }
    }

    public List<PdfText> GetCharacterData()
    {
      List<PdfText> retVal = new List<PdfText>();

      try
      {
        retVal = CharacterResult;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        ErrorManager.ReportError(ex);
      }

      return retVal;
    }

    public List<PdfText> GetWordData()
    {
      List<PdfText> retVal = new List<PdfText>();

      try
      {
        retVal = WordResult;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        ErrorManager.ReportError(ex);
      }

      return retVal;
    }

  }
```

```
  public class PdfText
  {

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Rectangle Rectangle { get; set; }
    public string FontFamily { get; set; }
    public int FontSize { get; set; }
    public float SpaceWidth { get; set; }
    public float CharacterSpacing { get; set; }
    public float Leading { get; set; }
    public float HorizontalScaling { get; set; }
    public Point3d StartPoint { get; set; }
    public Point3d EndPoint { get; set; }


  }
```

Comment: *"Things like Saskatchewan could be split into S A SKA TCH EWAN. Is there anyway to fix this?"* - do you mean you get separate events for "S", "A", "SKA", etc? Or do you mean you get an event "S A SKA..."?

Comment: @mkl I get separate events so when this line string curText = renderInfo.GetText(); runs in each event it will produce a different part of the string. I know that you've made posts to resolve this issue but I wasn't sure as to how I could implement them.

Comment: *"I get separate events"* - ok. This is completely normal. The event gets called individually for each and every separate string drawn in the content stream in question, and there is nothing requiring complete words to be drawn in a single string. There even is a reason for splitting words: that is the only way to apply kerning in pdfs. Thus, it is not an error that words come in in pieces, it is normal. As a consequence, therefore, the recipient of the events must collect information from the `TextRenderInfo` objects, sort them, check whether there are gaps between them separating words,...

Comment: @mkl Okay thanks I understand that now. Do you have any resources to help with the sorting and gap checking?

Comment: I think I was actually able to get something to work by copying similar code from the SimpleTextExtractionStrategy. I have added it to the main response. Thanks for guiding me in the right direction @mkl